# Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension, run local PowerShell Script using CustomScriptExtension

Tags: powershell, terraform

How to run a local ( without storing to a blob storage account ) PowerShell script in terraform  azurerm_virtual_machine_extension

Folder having

1. main.tf
2. install.ps1

   resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "software" {
         name                 = "install-software"
         resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.azrg.name
         virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
         publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
         type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
         type_handler_version = "1.9"

   ```
     settings = <<SETTINGS
       { 
         "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \"install.ps1\""
       } 
       SETTINGS
   }
   ```

   but failed

   ```
   [
           {
               "code": "ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded",
               "level": "Info",
               "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
               "message": "Windows PowerShell \r\nCopyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\n"
           },
           {
               "code": "ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded",
               "level": "Info",
               "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
               "message": "The argument 'install.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.\r\n"
           }
       ]
   ```

any lead.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

this worked for me.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "software" {
  name                 = "install-software"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.azrg.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(data.template_file.tf.rendered)}')) | Out-File -filepath install.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File install.ps1"
  }
  SETTINGS
}

data "template_file" "tf" {
    template = "${file("install.ps1")}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little bit prettier solution, based on [gsgill76's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60276573/6810344).
Note, that we should use [`textencodebase64`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/textencodebase64.html) (Terraform >= v0.14), because it allows to specify Unicode encoding ,which is expected by
`powershell -encodedCommand`.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "software" {
  name                 = "install-software"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.azrg.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
     "commandToExecute": "powershell -encodedCommand ${textencodebase64(file("install.ps1"), "UTF-16LE")}"
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get parameters to be passed from the data "template_file" into the PowerShell command line to execute on the server, if this helps anyone.

The credentials aren't actually needed in my case but I wanted to pass them anyway.  The creds are being taken from the VM setup in Azure in my case.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "software" {
  name                 = "install-software"
#  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.ADVM1.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
  {    
    "commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(data.template_file.DomainControllerSetup.rendered)}')) | Out-File -filepath DomainControllerSetup.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File DomainControllerSetup.ps1 -DomainName ${data.template_file.DomainControllerSetup.vars.DomainName} -AdmincredsUserName ${data.template_file.DomainControllerSetup.vars.AdmincredsUserName} -AdmincredsPassword ${data.template_file.DomainControllerSetup.vars.AdmincredsPassword}" 
  }
  
  SETTINGS
}

data "template_file" "DomainControllerSetup" {
    template = "${file("DomainControllerSetup.ps1")}"
    vars = {
        DomainName              = "azlab.local"
        AdmincredsUserName      = "${azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.ADVM1.admin_username}"
        AdmincredsPassword      = "${azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.ADVM1.admin_password}"
  }
}
```

This is  my "create new forest" script - again if it helps.  The creds aren't being used in this example, only the DomainName is used.  However i wanted to keep it in there in case I wanted to promote a member server into an existing domain.

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param 
( 
    [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$DomainName,
    [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$AdmincredsUserName,
    [Parameter(ValuefromPipeline=$true,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$AdmincredsPassword
)

$username = $AdmincredsUserName
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $AdmincredsPassword -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

install-windowsfeature AD-Domain-Services -IncludeManagementTools

Install-ADDSForest `
-DomainName $DomainName `
-SafeModeAdministratorPassword $password `
-CreateDnsDelegation:$false `
-DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-InstallDns:$true `
-LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false `
-SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
-Force:$true
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [gsgill76](/a/60276573/6810344) for the working command!

Here's how to use functions in favor of data sources

```
locals {
  scriptName     = "install.ps1"
  scriptRendered = filebase64("${path.module}/${local.scriptName}")
  # use templatefile() to parse script parameters
  ifTemplateFile = base64encode(templatefile("${path.module}/${local.scriptName}", {}))
  commandToExecute = jsonencode({
    commandToExecute = "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${local.scriptRendered}')) | Out-File -filepath ${local.scriptName}\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ${local.scriptName}"
  })
}

  # settings block will look like
  protected_settings = local.commandToExecute
```

`path.module` *assumes the script is located in the same directory as your terraform code*

> [filebase64](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/filebase64.html)
>
> [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html)
>
> [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html)