# Deploying tanium client on an azure virtual machine using terraform

Tags: azure, powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm using terraform to create Azure VMs and installed IIS as a n extension using PowerShell.

Now I want to install the Tanium Client on the Azure VM. Can I also do this as an extension using PowerShell or terraform or if there is any other way?

I'm quiet new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some bash or powershell script to download, install & configure tanium client. In such case, you can use extensions to copy to the remote machine & execute script.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "tanium-client-deployment" {
    name                 = "tanium-client"
    virtual_machine_id   = <vm-id>
    publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
    type                 = "CustomScript"
    type_handler_version = "2.0"
    
    protected_settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -command \"[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String('${base64encode(data.template_file.tf.rendered)}')) | Out-File -filepath install.ps1\" && powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File install-tanium.ps1"
    }
    SETTINGS
}
    
data "template_file" "tf" {
    template = "${file("install-tanium.ps1")}"
}
```

I got the template_file and a sample powershell command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60265902/terraform-azurerm-virtual-machine-extension-run-local-powershell-script-using-c).
If your script doesn't need any templating, you can avoid executing `template_file`, encode with [base64](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/filebase64) and pass it to `commandToExecute`