# Terraform azurerm_virtual_machine_extension, run local PowerShell Script using CustomScriptExtension with parameters

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have the following bit of tf code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "runscript" {
    virtual_machine_scale_set_id = subid

    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
    name                       = "RunCustomScript"
    publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                       = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version       = "1.8"
    protected_settings         = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
       "commandToExecute" : "powershell -encodedCommand ${textencodebase64(file("${path.module}/scripts/myscript.ps1"), "UTF-16LE") }"
    }
    PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

This is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165796). The script I want to use needs two parameters. I have been able to get one parameter working but am struggling to make it work with two.

I have tried this to work with one parameter:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "runscipt" {
    virtual_machine_scale_set_id = subid

    auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
    name                       = "RunCustomScript"
    publisher                  = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type                       = "CustomScriptExtension"
    type_handler_version       = "1.8"
    protected_settings         = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
       "commandToExecute" : "echo param1 | powershell -encodedCommand ${textencodebase64(file("${path.module}/scripts/myscript.ps1"), "UTF-16LE") }"
    }
    PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

I have tried putting both params there but that doesn't work. Would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

We can execute multiple commands using operators. try this approach.

**&&** - will execute the second command if the first is successful.
**||** - only executes the second command if the first one fails.

Here is the sample code to run multiple commands using Terraform.

```
commandToExecute : "echo param1 && apt-get -y update"
```

**Sample code snippet with azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension**

**Step1:**
Place below code in main tf file

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "rg-swarnademonew"
  location = "East US"
}
locals {
  first_public_key = "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC+wWK73dCr+jgQOAxNsHAnNNNMEFki5p2ZRJqcbCiF4pJrxUQR/RXqVFQdbRLZgYfJ8xGB878RENq3yQ39d8dVOkq4edbkzwcUmwwwkYVPIoDGsYLaRHnG+To7FvMeyO7xDVQkMKzopTQV8AuKpyvpqu0a9pWOMaiCyDytO7GGN you@me.com"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  name                = "example-vmss"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard_F2"
  instances           = 1
  admin_username      = "adminuser"

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = local.first_public_key
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_disk {
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
  }

  network_interface {
    name    = "example"
    primary = true

    ip_configuration {
      name      = "internal"
      primary   = true
      subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set_extension" "example" {
  name                         = "example"
  virtual_machine_scale_set_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine_scale_set.example.id
  publisher                    = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  type                         = "CustomScript"
  type_handler_version         = "2.0"
   protected_settings         = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute" : "echo param1 && apt-get -y update " 
    }
    PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

Provider tf file as

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }

}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Step2:
run below commands

```
Terraform plan
```

Output  as follows:

[image]

```
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

[image]

Verification from the portal

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for taking out the time. I think there has been a misunderstanding. I want to give one command which is "run this local script". I want to send two parameters to the script, to send one i can use piping like I showed in the example using '|' but can't figure out how to send two params. so it's a .ps1 file in my repo which takes two params

Comment: @Namji, please share .ps script file as well, so that will try to replicate the same.

Comment: Please refer this https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/how-to-use-templatefile-to-pass-a-powershell-script-into-commandtoexecute/17916